# Simple Vectors Problem

Tags: vectors

I hate to ask basic questions, but I'm struggling with some new concepts and applying them to questions I have.

The question is:

---

A plane is flying NE at its maximum velocity of 500 km/h according to its
instruments. However there is a northerly wind of 100 km.

(a) Sketch this situation on a vector diagram.

(b) Calculate the resultant velocity of the plane.

---

I don't have an issue with part (a), however I'm unsure about part (b). My thoughts are that it should simply be √ of 100^2 + 500^2, which is 509.90. Is this the correct way of going about a problem like this? Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: The key thing is that you're looking for the resultant **vector**. A vector has both a magnitude and direction.

Comment: Thanks, that is true, I forgot about this, I figure magnitude in this case would be 509.90 then, but that still leaves the issue of direction. As there are no definite angles stated how should I tackle this?

Comment: Presumably NE refers to $45^\circ$ assuming E to be the positive $x$-axis direction. However, an ambiguity (which I always found annoying when doing these problems myself back in the day) is that what does "northerly wind" mean? Is the wind blowing **from** the north, or is it blowing **to** the north? If one assumes this to mean blowing from the north, then the wind is blowing south, and thus has an angle of $270^\circ$ using our coordinate system.

Comment: Airspeed is measured in knots!

Comment: Also, the magnitude must be computed on the resultant vector. The way you computed the magnitude is in general false (think about it: if the wind is blowing against the movement of the aircraft, then its speed must be lower).

Comment: Thanks for that Dave, I think you're right, I'll have a go at working it out now with this in mind, and I'll be sure to let the publishers know of their inaccuracies Doug!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your sketch.

[image]

Black is the heading of the plane.
Red is the wind.  (wind blows from its indicated direction)
Blue is the course line.

Which angles, and which lengths do you know?

Mark up the figure appropreately.

Do you know any trig laws that might help, once you have the appropriate data?

And, if you are still stuck pull out your handy E6-B flight computer.

[image]

http://mye6b.com/e6b.html#_welcome

Comment: That's excellent, thank you for that. I think I should be able to apply trig laws to calculate this now it is clearer to understand.